# Resample based on a column value

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to resample this DataFrame :

```
import pandas as pd
from StringIO import StringIO

mycsv = StringIO("""
time;A;B
2015-12-06T22:00:00.000000Z;1.08703;1.1
2015-12-07T22:00:05.000000Z;1.08682;2.1
2015-12-07T22:00:05.000000Z;1.08682;3.5
2015-12-08T22:01:20.000000Z;1.08683;5.8
2015-12-09T22:01:30.000000Z;1.08676;6.1
2015-12-10T00:03:00.000000Z;1.08675;7.3
2015-12-06T22:03:50.000000Z;1.08676;12.0
""")
df = pd.read_csv(mycsv, delimiter=';', parse_dates=True, index_col='time', header=0)
```

each time the last column value is just <= 4 * k, where k is an integer, i.e. I want this result:

```
time;A;B
2015-12-07T22:00:05.000000Z;1.08682;3.5       # 3.5 is the last value <= 4.0
2015-12-10T00:03:00.000000Z;1.08675;7.3       # 7.3 is the last vakue <= 8.0
2015-12-06T22:03:50.000000Z;1.08676;12.0      # 1é.0 is the last value <= 12.0
```

**How to do this with pandas, i.e. resample based on a condition on a column?**

Comment: What is your resampling method? It looks like you're simply taking the last row that fits your criterion, not doing anything with the other rows that fit a criterion.

Comment: @Evert yes I want to keep rows number : `max {i such that B[i] <= 4}`, `max {i such that B[i] <= 8}`, `max {i such that B[i] <= 12}`, etc.

Comment: Not too Panda-esque, but a loop over `k` actually sounds easiest to implement.

Comment: I thought this was a common data-esque task : to resample at certain points, each time some amount B increases : here each time B increases of 4 units. Isn't there a panda way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to groupby division without remainder `//`:

```
In [11]: df.B // 4
Out[11]:
time
2015-12-06 22:00:00    0
2015-12-07 22:00:05    0
2015-12-07 22:00:05    0
2015-12-08 22:01:20    1
2015-12-09 22:01:30    1
2015-12-10 00:03:00    1
2015-12-06 22:03:50    3
Name: B, dtype: float64

In [12]: df.groupby(df.B // 4).last()
Out[12]:
         A     B
B
0  1.08682   3.5
1  1.08675   7.3
3  1.08676  12.0
```

Answer (score -1):

I would first remove the ones that are >4, then resample with the last:

```
In [11]: df[df["B"] <= 4]
Out[11]:
                           A    B
time
2015-12-06 22:00:00  1.08703  1.1
2015-12-07 22:00:05  1.08682  2.1
2015-12-07 22:00:05  1.08682  3.5

In [12]: df[df["B"] <= 4].resample("5min", "last")
...
```

If you don't want all the times in the middle, you have to use a groupby rather than resample:

```
In [21]: df[df["B"] < 4].groupby(level=0).last()
Out[21]:
                           A    B
time
2015-12-06 22:00:00  1.08703  1.1
2015-12-07 22:00:05  1.08682  3.5
```

Comment: It seems that there is a misunderstanding: this does not produce the desired result (see end of my question).